# using order by for month with year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table `Table1` with a column `Column1`  like this:

**Column1**

```
Dec-2010
Dec-2011
Feb-2011
Apr-2011
Jul-2011
May-2011
Aug-2011
Oct-2011
Sept-2011
Jan-2011
Mar-2011
Jun-2011
Nov-2011
Jan-2012
```

I want extract the data by using SELECT command as follows.

**Column1**

```
Dec-2010
Jan-2011
Feb-2011
Mar-2011
Apr-2011
May-2011
Jun-2011
Jul-2011
Aug-2011
Sep-2011
Oct-2011
Nov-2011
Dec-2011
Jan-2012
```

Kindly help me by providing a SELECT query to retrieve the data as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) your column to datetime and order by that.

```
select Column1
from YourTable
order by convert(datetime, left(Column1, 3)+' 01, '+right(Column1, 4), 107)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `CAST('01-' + Column1 AS DATETIME)` work just as well?

Comment: @marc_s - I guess it should work but not with the input data provided here `Sept`. It might be a typo because in the result it is `Sep`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution which does not involve mucking with your `VARCHAR` column (or so I assume) other than to `replace` the `-` character:

```
SELECT  Column1
FROM    Table1
ORDER BY
        CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(Column1, '-', ' '))
```

Comment: As per the comments on the other answer, this solution will not work if the `September` dates are stored as `Sept`--we're assuming a three-character month.  Also, yes, please **accept** the answer if you used it.

Answer (score 0):

if your column datatype is a DATE, then just give order by column name

```
SELECT * from TABLE_NAME 
ORDER BY COL1;
```

by Default it arranges in Ascending order.